# Marked as duplicate but no currently-visible link to duplicate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions

[rails run specific migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316889/rails-run-specific-migration) is marked as an exact duplicate, but there's no non-deleted content indicating what it is a duplicate of.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316893/38765 contains a link to the duplicate, as do past [versions of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1316889/revisions), but nothing immediately visible to normal users.

As the question has a net score of 52, and 22 favorites, and one answer has 132 net votes, I suggest deleting this post is not the optimal solution.

Comment: I like how this duplicate link points to a page with a duplicate link pointing towards the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1316889/revisions). Specifically, the diff between revisions 3 and 4. A user disagreed with the closure and "resolved" the issue by editing the duplicate link out of the question. This was possible back then since the links were just inserted into the post's contents.

You could just roll back the last edit, but I reopened and reclosed to prevent this from happening again on the same question.

If the question truly is not a duplicate, it should be either edited to explain how it's different *or*, given its age, its closure should be contested on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Someone other than the OP did that edit.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm D'oh, you're right. Still comes out to the same thing, though.

Comment: Yeah, I do the Reopen/Close again trick sometimes using my hammer, when I spot a chance.